# Create Pico process with associated provider

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, process, windows-10

I recently started looking into the topics of Pico processes (see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/05/23/pico-process-overview/) and [here](http://www.alex-ionescu.com/publications/BlueHat/bluehat2016.pdf)). I also started reading the `Windows Internals 7th Edition Part 1` book.

As stated in the book, currently there is no API available for creating custom Pico processes and providers. However, I thought it would be possible to create a Pico process or provider from within a kernel driver, since the definition of a Pico process is declared as:

`[...] the idea of a Pico provider is defined, which is a custom kernel-mode driver that receives access to specialized kernel interfaces through the PsRegisterPicoProvider API.` - *Windows Internals 7th Edition Part 1, p. 68*

Unfortunately when creating a new kernel-mode driver in Visual Studio 2015 just like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver), there doesn't seem to be any available headers or interfaces which allow creating Pico processes and providers. I only seem to be able to write other kind of KMDF projects.

Is there currently *any* way for developers to create and test custom Pico processes and providers in Windows?

Comment: you can create dll project for example

Answer (score 4):

[Martin Hron](https://github.com/thinkcz) wrote a little experiment with Pico Providers a couple years ago. In it, he included some assembly references, header files, and external C interfaces that included a driver for a Pico Process monitor tool. I'm not sure if his code still works, but it can give you an insight into which headers and structs that you'd need to interface with.

https://github.com/thinkcz/pico-toolbox

YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

### 2023 answer for Windows 23H2:

#### Short answer

Yes, there *is*.

#### Long answer

The function required for Pico providers to register themselves is `PsRegisterPicoProvider`. This function is exported to kernel drivers, but is useless for third-party drivers, since it is guarded by a flag, `PspPicoRegistrationDisabled`.

According to the materials linked in the question, `PspPicoRegistrationDisabled` is protected by PatchGuard. However, as of Windows 11 23H2, this no longer seems to be the case. Modifying the flag on a machine without debug mode turned on no longer results in an instant BSoD.

You can use the disassembly method to guess the address of `PspPicoRegistrationDisabled` as presented in thinkcz's [Pico Toolbox](https://github.com/thinkcz/pico-toolbox/blob/8ea692ac6dcb93c47917f854fda08621aa623271/ToolBoxDriver/tools.cpp#L126-L134) (which is quite fragile, causes a bug check in Windows 11 23H2), or (ab)use PDB files to [generate the offsets for all known Windows versions](https://github.com/trungnt2910/PspPicoProviderRoutinesOffsetGen) (which requires periodic updates).

However, since Windows only stores Pico provider callbacks in a single structure (`PspPicoProviderRoutines`), it has no way to allow two Pico providers to coexist. A hypothetical successful call to `PsRegisterPicoProvider` would unregister the previous driver.

The [`lxmonika`](https://github.com/trungnt2910/lxmonika/tree/master/lxmonika) support driver both handles the offset-guessing issue using a table of known offsets with some heuristics for unknown Windows versions and allows up to 16 Pico providers to coexist with each other, including `lxcore`. To use `lxmonika`, just create a usual Visual Studio KMDF template, add a reference to the `lxmonika` headers and glue libraries, and then call `MaRegisterPicoProvider` with the same interface instead of the `Ps*` counterpart.

There is also a sample driver, [`mxss`](https://github.com/trungnt2910/lxmonika/tree/master/mxss), capable of printing hello world using a custom syscall ABI.

Note that finding a workaround for Windows's Pico process restrictions is only the tip of the iceberg. One would expect having to wade through tons of undocumented interfaces and experience dozens of BSoDs before getting even the simplest `"Hello World!"`s running.

Comment: This is the best answer I've seen about Windows in a long time, thank you! And also, this feels a bit anti-competitive for this to be hidden so far down... but such is Windows!